# Exercise 6, section 2.7 of Hammack's Book of Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have two questions about exercise 6 of section 2.7 of  Book of Proof from Hammack.

The exercise asks the reader to write the following statement in English and then to say if the statement is true or false.

$$ \exists \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \vert X \vert < n $$

My first question is whether or not I am reading this correctly.
I interpret this statement as saying "there exists a positive integer greater than the cardinality of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$". Is that correct?

My second question, assuming my understanding of the statement is correct, is whether the statement is true or not.
My fist line of thought was that the statement is false because for any positive integer $n$ there will always be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with cardinality equal or larger than $n$ since the set of natural numbers is infinitely large. However, the converse reasoning seems as valid: for any subset of $\mathbb{N}$, however large it is, there will always exist a positive integer larger than this subset's cardinality. It seems to me now that we cannot really say if the statement is true or false: the statement itself is sort of paradoxical. Would this assessment be the correct answer? Am I missing something here?

Comment: First answer correct: the statement is false.

Comment: Second thought wrong: if you swap quantifiers you change the meaning of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My fist line of thought was that the statement is false because for any positive integer $n$ there will always be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with cardinality equal or larger than $n$ since the set of natural numbers is infinitely large.

Yes, pretty much ... but you want to be a little more explicit/concrete about exactly what subset you can always pick such that its cardinality is not smaller than $n$ for whatever number $n$ you may have picked initially. But it is easy to see what works: you can pick any infinite-sized subset, such as all even numbers ... or even just simply $\mathbb{N}$ itself ... which is also an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

> However, the converse reasoning seems as valid: for any subset of $\mathbb{N}$, however large it is, there will always exist a positive integer larger than this subset's cardinality.

First of all, you are now considering the truth of the statement:

$$ \forall X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \exists \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \vert X \vert < n $$

which is a different statement. But, like the original one, this one is also false. Again, you can use any infinite-sized subset as a counterexample.

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, because $n$ is by definition finite and because $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ contains sets with infinite cardinality, the statement is always false?

Comment: What you say is correct, but the issue is not specifically the fact that there are infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$. Suppose $\mathcal F(\mathbb N)$ were the collection of all *finite* subsets of $\mathbb N$. Then while the analogous statement $\exists \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall X \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}), \vert X \vert < n$ would still false, the statement with interchanged quantifiers,  $\forall X \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}), \exists \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \vert X \vert < n$, would be true. At the heart of the OP’s question is a somewhat fuzzy understanding of the order of quantifiers.

Comment: @SteveKass Thanks! I guess I phrased that poorly ... yes, it isn't the fact that there are infintiely many subsets .. but I meant infinite-sized subsets. I edited it. Does it read better now?

Comment: @madibam Yes, that's it.  But also take a good look at how the order of the quantifiers matters, as several commentators and I have pointed out.

Comment: @SteveKass, I see how in my second line of thought I swapped the quantifiers which results in an entirely different statement. However, isn't it the case that there will always exist an integer that is larger than the cardinality of any subset of the positive integers? Just like you say the statement if false because you can always pick an infinite subset, can't you also pick a $n$ that is infinitely large?

Comment: There is no integer $n$ that is larger than every finite subset of $\mathbb N$. (There is no “infinitely large integer.”)

Comment: What you may be missing is the difference between 1) the statement in the exercise, that there is some specific integer $n$ (that does not depend on $X$) that is larger than $|X|$ (no matter what $X$ is). and 2) the reversed-quantifier statement, that given a particular $X$, there is some integer $n$ (but the choice may depend on $X$) that is larger than that particular $|X|$. The first statement is false for $X$ in either $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ or $\mathcal F(\mathbb N)$, but the second statement is true if the universal quantifier is $\forall\mathcal F(\mathbb N)$

Comment: @madibam Absolutely correct. As I said in my Answer, both the original statement, as well as the one where you swap the quantifiers, are false. In both cases you can consider infinite-sized subsets for a counterexample.

Comment: @SteveKass All true ... but neither statement (not the original, nor the one with quantifiers swapped) is restricting itself to only finite-sized subsets

Comment: I think I have a problem wrapping my mind around the fact that even when considering only the finite subsets $X$ of $\mathbb{N}$, or $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N})$, there does not exist an integer that is larger than $\vert X \vert$ no matter what the finite subset $X$ is. How is that the case? Can't we always find a larger integer that would make the statement ∃ n∈N,∀X∈F(N),|X|<n true?

Comment: @madibam Ah!  OK, well, let's say you pick a number $n$. Is that number goung to be rgeater than the cardinality of any finite-sized subset? No. Take the subset of all numbers $1$ through $n$.  That subset has cardinality $n$ ... and so obviously $n$ is not going to be greater than that cardiniality. So yes, for every number $n$ that you pick, I can pick a finite-sized subset such that its cardinality is not smaller than $n$. But if we reverse the quantifiers:  if I pick whatever finite-sized subset, you can always pick a number that is greater than the cardinality of that specific subset.

Comment: Okay I think this is actually starting to make sense. I'll ponder some more on this, but I think I see how the order of the quantifiers impacts the logical statement. Thank you for helping me push my understanding, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @madibam  Maybe this further helps: compare the statements $\forall x \exists y \ x < y$ and  $\exists y \forall x \ x < y$. The first is true: for every number that I pick, you can pick a larger one. But the second is false: I cannot pick a number that is greater than all numbers.